# Conflict between two js scripts (galleria and multi-screen)

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleria

I've tried looking this up, but I can't seem to find anything that makes sense to me.
I have this project in which two of my scripts seem to be clashing. One of them is multi-screen.js ( http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Full-Page-Slide-Transitions-with-jQuery-Multi-Screen-js-Plugin.html )and the other is galleria.js.

If I comment out multiscreen, then galleria works perfectly, but if multiscreen is active then the navigation in the galleria gallery wont work - it just shows the pictures and the thumbnails.

So it seems like multi-screen is blocking some of the functionality out of other scripts.

I hope someone could tell how to sort this thing out, as it is driving me mad.

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script src="js/galleria/galleria-1.3.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/multi-screen.js"></script>
<!-- run the plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() { MultiScreen.init(); });</script>
```

Comment: check this out http://interface88.blogspot.in/2012/07/using-multiple-version-of-jquery-on.html

Comment: Without knowing what "multi-screen" is, it's hard to say. Do you get errors in the browser console?

Comment: Maybe both libraries use the same variable name for a global variable.

Comment: Multi-screen is this animation plugin http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Full-Page-Slide-Transitions-with-jQuery-Multi-Screen-js-Plugin.html

I don't get any other console errors than this; Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

But this is related to something else in the code - a mediaplayer. I wouldn't think, that it interfered with the abovementioned.